# Can I connect a container/service in a swarm using dnsrr (dns round robin) instead of an IP

Tags: docker

version: '3.7'
services:
db:
image: "mysql:5.7"
healthcheck:
test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'mysqladmin ping']
interval: 10s
timeout: 5s
retries: 10
ports:
- target: 3306
published: 3306
protocol: tcp
mode: host

```
deploy:
  endpoint_mode: dnsrr
  mode: "replicated"
  replicas: 2
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 2G
volumes:
  - foo:/var/lib/mysql

environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/my_file_secret
secrets:
  - my_file_secret
```

secrets:
my_file_secret:
file: ./my_file_secret.txt

volumes:
foo:
driver: local

Comment: You want to build your own base image instead of blablahblah/cron:v? Otherwise just use this dockerfile to build your own image.

Comment: I'm not sure what your security concerns are, but you can generally inject your own environment variables and config files at `docker run` time, and if you have the image, you can run `docker history` on it to see things like those `ENV` variables.

Comment: What do you think?